# How to dynamically create a string based on a range of values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, have a list of customers (col A) who bought a product, and they paid different prices (col B) depending on when they bought it and if they used a discount code.

I need to generate a string to show the number of people who bought the product at each price. So the string should look like this, showing that 1 customer paid £30, 4 customers paid £33.50, etc.

```
1@30 + 4@33.5 + 24@34 + 1@34.5 + 23*35 + 17@37 + 12@37.5
```

If price was a fixed amount then I could use COUNTIF and SUMIF and hard-code the price into the formula. But the price is constantly changing and the list is growing. So I need a formula that can create as long a string as necessary. How can this be done?

Here's the Google Sheet with the list of customers who purchased the product at different prices, and an example of the desired result:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WmIXmkKmZOVcJ4dXxzy0CXbRCMya3uAdWk8yKhA50rw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 , here's the Google Sheet with an example of the desired result: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WmIXmkKmZOVcJ4dXxzy0CXbRCMya3uAdWk8yKhA50rw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, nested QUERYs should do it. Try this (assuming your prices are in Column B as stated in the post):

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(" + ",QUERY(QUERY(B:B,"Select COUNT(B), B Where B Is Not Null Group By B Order By B Asc Label COUNT(B) ''",0),"Select Col1")&"@"&QUERY(QUERY(B:B,"Select COUNT(B), B Where B Is Not Null Group By B Order By B Asc Label COUNT(B) ''",0),"Select Col2")))
```

I encourage you to look at what the central QUERY does on its own:

```
QUERY(B:B,"Select COUNT(B), B Where B Is Not Null Group By B Order By B Asc Label COUNT(B) ''",0)
```

The other two outer QUERYs act on that data to concatenate the first column plus "@" plus the second column.

Then JOIN just takes that virtual vertical list and forms one string with " + " between each element.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your answer. It does work but I was intending to take it a step further by dividing it by month, but this formula is a little more complicated than I was thinking. Can you please help me figure out how to do this? Columns A, B and C contain the date, customer, and amount. And column E contains the month I want to summarise, and column F is where I want to have the output string.

Here's a google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WmIXmkKmZOVcJ4dXxzy0CXbRCMya3uAdWk8yKhA50rw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tim, I only hop on here every so often "for fun," assuming that the posts I respond to accurately portray the scope of the issue. I stay very busy with client work, so I can't get into extended projects here. That said, if you can wait, I'll bookmark this and take another look next time I've got a free block. In the meantime, someone else here may very well beat me to the punch.

Comment: Thanks Erik, you have answered the original question and I'm grateful for that. I'll try to figure out dividing it by month, otherwise I'll ask a new question. Cheers

Comment: Tim B, I added a sheet to your spreadsheet wherein I've provided a solution with notes.